# how to assign defined radio button layout to dynamic radio button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I have defined xml for radio button in activity_main.xml. In main activity i am trying to add radio buttons to radio group dynamically. 
facing this error

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

```
RadioGroup answerOptions = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.answers_options);


    for (int i = 0; i < answersList.size() ; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
        radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.simpleRadioButton);
        radioButton.setText(answersList.get(i).getOption_description());
        answerOptions.addView(radioButton,i);
    }
```

some part of main_activity.xml

```
    <RadioGroup

        android:id="@+id/answers_options"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RadioButton
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:id="@+id/simpleRadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.20"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Please provide a complete example. In particular, you should have a complete Activity or Fragment class that contains the code you are asking about (most likely in onCreate() or onCreateView()). You should also give a complete XML layout file. This means that you should have a valid root element such as LinearLayout or RelativeLayout. Note **this does not mean post all of your code**. You should still only post what is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are getting a reference to the same RadioButton that is defined in your xml.

Try doing:

```
for (int i = 0; i < answersList.size() ; i++) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
    radioButton.setText(answersList.get(i).getOption_description());
    answerOptions.addView(radioButton,i);
}
```

To set the same properties defined in xml you could do it programmatically or create a new layout and inflate it.